# Laptop screen rotated NOT in Windows

Tags: display, bios

I have a strange issue with a laptop which the screen has rotated 90 degrees but not in Windows. Even when going into the BIOS the screen is rotated and I think that this is causing an issue in Windows itself.

Using American Megatrend Aptio setup utility BIOS but can not find anything in there regarding screen rotation.

The Intel graphics app within windows is set to rotate to normal view once in windows. Even the windows startup screen is wrongly rotated.

Comment: the screen in BIOS is not related to Windows in any way. Make sure that you've installed graphics driver correctly

Comment: I know that. It's not a windows issue as the windows driver is used to put the screen rotation right only when windows has started. But when reading bios settings or laptop startup messages or windows startup it's rotation is wrong.

Comment: the BIOS screen can't be rotated

Comment: Well this one is in portrait mode rather than landscape.